# Disable sonarqube in macro

Tags: c++, sonarqube

Sonarqube's cognitive complexity score is getting artificially increased by many calls to a logging macro in my codebase. I wish to have sonarqube ignore all calls to that macro during the complexity analysis since it is just logging and does not actually effect the humanly readable complexity. Normally, I would be able to put the '//NOSONAR' comment on a line of code to keep sonarqube from considering it in the complexity analysis. Is there a way to modify the macro such that any calls to it are automatically removed from the scan? As I understand it, the preprocessor removes any comments before it performs macro expansions, and so just including the '//NOSONAR' comment within the macro does not have any effect. Is there any way to get around this? It would be really inconvenient to have to comment every call to the logger with the sonar exclusion.

Comment: I bumped into the same issue, and asked on Sonar Community. Macros with incomplete syntactic constructs are evaluated like this on purpose. They suggested an alternative syntax that should work, but not viable at least in my case. See: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/c-cognitive-complexity-rule-counts-macro-contents/67322